# 1. I am trying to validate the number of parameters passed to shell script, but I am not able to find the simple way

Tags: jquery, shell, validation, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am trying to write validation for two different scripts as per the below requirement,

1. I am trying to validate whether all the required parameters are passed to shell script, but I am not able to find the right way since getopts does not support long variables.

`members.sh -name [name] -age [age] -sex [m/f] -add [address] -city [city] -country [country] -pincode [pincode] - mobile [mobile no] -email [email id]`

I want to pass the above parameters, `mobile` and `email` are optional remaining are mandatory options and `age`, `pincode` should be only numeric and if we provide the mobile no then that is also should be in integer.

How can I validate the above? Thanks for your help in advance

1. For another script I need to allow only one option among several, how can I achieve this.

Example:

```
listhistory.sh -all -name [name] -mobile [mobile no] .... -opt9 [data9]
```

the above script should be called using `-all` or `-name [name]` or `-mobile [mobile no]` or any other argument within 9 arguments.

Comment: have you tried getopts ?

Comment: yes but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to modify your requirement a little bit and use the script like :

members.sh --name [name] --age [age] --sex [m/f] --add [address] --city [city]  --mobile [mobile no] --email [email id]

If that is OK with you.. you might consider writing something like :

```
#!/bin/sh

while getopts ":-:" arg
do
        case "${arg}" in
            -)
                 case "${OPTARG}" in
                        sex)
                            val="${!OPTIND}"; OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))
                            echo "Parsing option: '--${OPTARG}', value: '${val}'" >&2;
                            sex=${val};
                           ;;
                        age)
                            val="${!OPTIND}"; OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))
                            echo "Parsing option: '--${OPTARG}', value: '${val}'" >&2;
                            age=${val};
                            ;;
                        name)
                            val="${!OPTIND}"; OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))
                            echo "Parsing option: '--${OPTARG}', value: '${val}'" >&2;
                            name=${val};
                            ;;
                        add)
                            val="${!OPTIND}"; OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))
                            echo "Parsing option: '--${OPTARG}', value: '${val}'" >&2;
                            add=${val};
                            ;;
                        city)
                            val="${!OPTIND}"; OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))
                            echo "Parsing option: '--${OPTARG}', value: '${val}'" >&2;
                            city=${val};
                            ;;
                        mobile)
                            val="${!OPTIND}"; OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))
                            echo "Parsing option: '--${OPTARG}', value: '${val}'" >&2;
                            mobile=${val};
                            ;;
                        email)
                            val="${!OPTIND}"; OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))
                            echo "Parsing option: '--${OPTARG}', value: '${val}'" >&2;
                            email=${val};
                            ;;
                    esac;;
        esac
done


err=0;
if [ -z "${sex+xxx}" ]; then echo sex is not set at all; err=1;fi
if [ -z "${name+xxx}" ]; then echo name is not set at all;err=1; fi
if [ -z "${age+xxx}" ]; then echo age is not set at all; err=1; fi
if [ -z "${city+xxx}" ]; then echo city is not set at all; err=1; fi
if [ -z "${add+xxx}" ]; then echo add is not set at all; err=1; fi

if [[ $err -eq 1 ]]
then
        echo "incorrect usage"
        exit 1
else
        echo "All mandatory fields are set"
fi
```

P.S: I have not covered all the required fields .. basing my solution on making 5 of the arguments [name, age, sex, city and add] as mandatory.. while phone and e-mail are optional arguments..

The code just takes input and stored them in a variable.. please write your own code for further validation.

Sample output:

```
$ sh n.sh --name nishant --age 24 --sex M --add "New Delhi India" --city Noida
Parsing option: '--name', value: 'nishant'
Parsing option: '--age', value: '24'
Parsing option: '--sex', value: 'M'
Parsing option: '--add', value: 'New Delhi India'
Parsing option: '--city', value: 'Noida'
All mandatory fields are set
```

Comment: Thank a lot Nishant, it works fine, but I need to use only one - not -- example
sh n.sh -name nishant -age 24 -sex M -add "New Delhi India" -city Noida
is there any other way to make the script works for single -